# Referencing its own function inside .after in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have trouble calling the function name in the .after method.

```
def game(self):
        self._root.after(self._root,1000,function = game)
```

Comment: Should be `self._root.after(1000, self.game)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `after` is the time period. The second argument is the function to call. You have an extra argument before the time period.

```
self._root.after(1000, self.game)
```